# SAPUI5-How to bind data to sap.ui.layout.form?

Tags: sapui5

How to bind json data to form.Below is my form and data to be binded.
    Please help me with this.
    Example i want to bind 111 object values to the form

```
Data:
{"customerdetailsjson": {
        "111": [
            {
                "name": "Bhuvaneswari Krishnan",
               "phone-number":"8050231233"
            }
        ],
        "112": [
            {
                 "name":"Chetan Sandeep Renu",
       "phone-number":"9840321321"
            }
        ]
    }}

Form:
var oLayout1 = new sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveGridLayout();
customerDetailsForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.Form("F1", {
layout: oLayout1,
formContainers: [new sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer("F1C2", {
    title: new sap.ui.core.Title({
        text: "Address Information",
        tooltip: "Address data"
    }),
    formElements: [new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
        label: "Street / Number",
        fields: [new sap.m.Input({
            type: sap.m.InputType.Text,
            value: "{name}",
            layoutData: new sap.ui.core.VariantLayoutData({
                multipleLayoutData: [new sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveFlowLayoutData({
                    weight: 5
                }), new sap.ui.layout.form.GridElementData({
                    hCells: "5"
                })]
            })
        })]
    }), new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
        label: "Street / Number",
        fields: [new sap.m.Input({
            type: sap.m.InputType.Text,
            value: "{phone-number}",
            layoutData: new sap.ui.core.VariantLayoutData({
                multipleLayoutData: [new sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveFlowLayoutData({
                    weight: 5
                }), new sap.ui.layout.form.GridElementData({
                    hCells: "5"
                })]
            })
        })]
    })]
})]
})]
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need a model:

```
var myModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(myJsonData);
```

Then you assign it to your control:

```
customerDetailsForm.setModel(myModel);
```

Now you can start binding values from your model to the control (and also sub-controls) by using an absolute path from the root node of your model:

```
    ...
    new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
            label: "Street / Number",
            fields: [new sap.m.Input({
                type: sap.m.InputType.Text,
                value: "{/customerdetailsjson/111/0/name}",
                layoutData: new sap.ui.core.VariantLayoutData({
                    multipleLayoutData: [new sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveFlowLayoutData({
                        weight: 5
                    }), new sap.ui.layout.form.GridElementData({
                        hCells: "5"
                    })]
                })
            })]
   ...
```

GL
Chris

Comment: Hi,

     Thanks for the reply.One doubt in this 

value: "{/customerdetailsjson/111/0/name}"  Can we make this customerdetailsjson/111 as dynamic using bindContext or something?Pls help me

Comment: 1. you could get rid of the unneccessary array inside 110 2. If your parent control allows for an aggregation binding e.g. items on sap.m.List you can bind against an array in your data e.g. "{/customerdetailsjson/111}" and use relative (no leading "/") bindings inside the repeated control e.g. sap.m.DisplayListItem like this "{name}"

Comment: @Papu btw: you could mark my answer as correct if it helped. Thanks